# Resampling trade data into OHLCV with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have historical trade data in a pandas DataFrame, containing price and volume columns, indexed by a DateTimeIndex.

For example:

```
>>> print df.tail()
                             price  volume
2014-01-15 14:29:54+00:00  949.975    0.01
2014-01-15 14:29:59+00:00  941.370    0.01
2014-01-15 14:30:17+00:00  949.975    0.01
2014-01-15 14:30:24+00:00  941.370    0.01
2014-01-15 14:30:36+00:00  949.975    0.01
```

Now, I can resample this into OHLC data using `df.resample(freq, how={'price': 'ohlc'})`, which is fine, but I'd also like to include the volume.

When I try `df.resample(freq, how={'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})`, I get:

`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2,), indices imply (2, 95)`

I'm not quite sure what is wrong with my dataset, or why this fails. Could anyone help shed some light on this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

The problem isn't with the resampling, it's from trying to concat a MultiIndex (from the price OHLC), with a regular index (for the Volume sum).

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
                       price  volume
2014-01-15 14:29:54  949.975    0.01
2014-01-15 14:29:59  941.370    0.01
2014-01-15 14:30:17  949.975    0.01
2014-01-15 14:30:24  941.370    0.01
2014-01-15 14:30:36  949.975    0.01

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [18]: df.resample('30s', how={'price': 'ohlc'})  # Note the MultiIndex
Out[18]: 
                       price                           
                        open     high      low    close
2014-01-15 14:29:30  949.975  949.975  941.370  941.370
2014-01-15 14:30:00  949.975  949.975  941.370  941.370
2014-01-15 14:30:30  949.975  949.975  949.975  949.975

[3 rows x 4 columns]

In [19]: df.resample('30s', how={'volume': 'sum'})  # Regular Index for columns
Out[19]: 
                     volume
2014-01-15 14:29:30    0.02
2014-01-15 14:30:00    0.02
2014-01-15 14:30:30    0.01

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

I guess you could manually create a MultiIndex for `(volume, sum)` and then concat:

```
In [34]: vol = df.resample('30s', how={'volume': 'sum'})

In [35]: vol.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('volume', 'sum')])

In [36]: vol
Out[36]: 
                     volume
                        sum
2014-01-15 14:29:30    0.02
2014-01-15 14:30:00    0.02
2014-01-15 14:30:30    0.01

[3 rows x 1 columns]

In [37]: price = df.resample('30s', how={'price': 'ohlc'})

In [38]: pd.concat([price, vol], axis=1)
Out[38]: 
                       price                             volume
                        open     high      low    close     sum
2014-01-15 14:29:30  949.975  949.975  941.370  941.370    0.02
2014-01-15 14:30:00  949.975  949.975  941.370  941.370    0.02
2014-01-15 14:30:30  949.975  949.975  949.975  949.975    0.01

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

But it might be better if resample could handle this automatically.

Comment: This seems to be resolved with new resample API (`df.resample('30S').agg({'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})`).

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this in later versions of Pandas
Example: Pandas version 0.22.00 `df.resample('30S').mean()`

Answer (score 1):

```py
price = df['price'].resample('30s').ohlc(_method='ohlc')
volume = df['volume'].resample('30s').sum()
data = pd.concat([price, volume], axis=1)
```

```
                        open     high      low    close  volume
2014-01-15 14:29:30  949.975  949.975  941.370  941.370    0.02
2014-01-15 14:30:00  949.975  949.975  941.370  941.370    0.02
2014-01-15 14:30:30  949.975  949.975  949.975  949.975    0.01
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).